# How to visualize a decision tree classifier?

Tags: python, data-mining, decision-trees, visualization, classifier

I'm using ID3 algorithm to build a classifier and was wondering if there is any way to visualize the decision tree that the algorithm builds.
This is my code for a decision tree in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # data visualization
import seaborn as sns # statistical data visualization
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
import math

def id3(data, target, features, default=0):
    """
    Implements the ID3 algorithm for decision tree classification.

    Args:
        data: A list of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents a data point
              with keys for features and the target variable.
        target: The name of the target variable in the data.
        features: A list of feature names.
        default: The default class value to return if no majority class is found
                 at a node (optional, defaults to 0).

    Returns:
        A decision tree represented as a dictionary.
    """

    # Check if all data points have the same target value (base case)
    if all(data[0][target] == row[target] for row in data):
        return {target: data[0][target]}

    # Check if there are no remaining features (base case)
    if not features:
        # Majority vote for class label
        class_counts = defaultdict(int)
        for row in data:
            class_counts[row[target]] += 1
        return {target: max(class_counts, key=class_counts.get)}

    # Calculate entropy of the target variable
    entropy = _calculate_entropy(data, target)

    # Find the feature with the highest information gain
    best_feature, best_gain = None, -float('inf')
    for feature in features:
        gain = _calculate_information_gain(data, target, feature, entropy)
        if gain > best_gain:
            best_feature = feature
            best_gain = gain

    # Print information gain for this feature
        print(f"Feature '{feature}': Information Gain = {gain:.4f}")

    # Create a new decision tree node
    tree = {best_feature: {}}

    # Remove the best feature from the remaining features list
    remaining_features = features.copy()
    remaining_features.remove(best_feature)

    # Group data based on the best feature's values
    feature_values = set(row[best_feature] for row in data)
    for value in feature_values:
        # Filter data points with the current feature value
        subset_data = [row for row in data if row[best_feature] == value]

        # Print detailed calculations:
        print(f"Data for feature '{best_feature}' = '{value}':")
        print(f"- Entropy: {entropy:.4f}")  # Format entropy with 4 decimal places
        print(f"- Feature value: '{value}'")
        print(f"- Subset data:", subset_data)

        # Recursively build subtrees for each value of the best feature
        subtree = id3(subset_data, target, remaining_features, default)
        tree[best_feature][value] = subtree

    return tree

def _calculate_entropy(data, target):
    """Calculates the entropy of the target variable."""
    class_counts = defaultdict(int)
    for row in data:
        class_counts[row[target]] += 1

    entropy = 0
    for count in class_counts.values():
        if count > 0:
            p = count / len(data)
            entropy -= p * math.log2(p)

    return entropy

def _calculate_information_gain(data, target, feature, entropy):
    """Calculates the information gain for a given feature."""
    feature_values = set(row[feature] for row in data)
    information_gain = entropy

    for value in feature_values:
        subset_data = [row for row in data if row[feature] == value]
        subset_entropy = _calculate_entropy(subset_data, target)
        information_gain -= len(subset_data) / len(data) * subset_entropy

    return information_gain




#Import DataSet
dataC1=pd.read_csv("DataClass_Table.csv", sep=",", engine='python')
dataC1['isFraud'].value_counts()
   
#Declare feature vector and target variable 
features = list(dataC1.columns)
target = features.pop()

# Converted data
data_list = dataC1.to_dict('records')

# Split data (replace 0.2 with your desired test size)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data_list, target, test_size=0.2)

#Call ID3 Function
decision_tree = id3(X_train, target, features)
print(decision_tree)
```

How can I make the tree drawing with nodes like this?
[image: Decision Tree Visualization]